# Grassmannian manifold and corresponding vector field

Tags: vector-bundles, grassmannian

I am assuming the definition of Grassmannian is known. 
Reference is [Vector bundles and K-theory](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) page no 28.

I am trying to prove that the map $p:E_n(\mathbb{R}^k)\rightarrow G(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is a vector bundle.

In particular I want to prove it is locally trivial.

Given $l\in G(\mathbb{R}^k)$ I want to produce an open set $U$ containing $l$ and some local trivialisation. That notes has already mentioned that theory choice of $U$ is $$\{l’\in G(\mathbb{R}^k):\pi_l(l’)\text{ has dimension } n\}$$
where $\pi_l:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow l$ is orthogonal projection onto $l$.

I fail to see what is the motivation for choosing such $U$.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: What is $\pi$? (Presumably some fixed projection onto n coordinates?) Drawing pictures for the case of lines in the plane should be illuminating. E.g. for pi the projection onto the x axis, you are left with all lines that can be written as $y = ax $, and the parameter a provides the trivialization. (The only missing line is the vertical line $x = 0$, that's in the other patch, projection onto y axis.)

Comment: I do not completely understand your comment... I have added what is $\pi$...@Lorenzo I did draw the picture but did not get the clear idea.. Can you explain little more...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I edited your question to reflect the notation of the notes ($\pi_l$).

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The lines that are not vertical can be described by a single number, the slope. This is the coordinatization of one patch for the Grassmannian of lines in the plane. In other words, we're working with graph of certain linear transformations.

Comment: Thanks @KyleMiller

Comment: Then think about the case of lines in 3 space - we have the vectors (1,a,b) and these define certain transformation ... Just as before the transformation was determined by the vector (1,a). Here we're looking at the image of a linear transformation.

Comment: @Lorenzo I am somehow missing your point... Given a line $l$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , I have to choose a collection of lines which forms an open set in $G_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$... I understand lines that are not vertical can be described by a single number but I do not see how it is related to looking for a collection of lines....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik the collection of lines is the set of non vertical lines. I'm describing patches on the simplest nontrivial Grassmannian. The coordinates in this case have a familiar interpretation - slope. The points in the tautological bundle above the line a can be described by the mapping x goes to (x, ax), for x a real number . The coordinates for E above this patch are the slope a and x. I'm recommending you start with this simple example, and draw some pictures. You can also draw what the transition between the two patches does to the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to understand the case of the tautological vector bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^k$ first, rather than the general case of $G_n(\mathbb{R}^k)$. (So, let $n=1$.)  We think of $\mathbb{R}P^k$ to be the space of $1$-dimensional vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

We have $E_1(\mathbb{R}^k)=\{(\ell,v):\ell\in \mathbb{R}P^k\text{ and }v\in\ell\}$ and a map $p:E_1(\mathbb{R}^k)\to\mathbb{R}P^k$ defined by $p(\ell,v)=\ell$.  The hope is that $p$ forms a vector bundle, whose fibers over a point $\ell\in\mathbb{R}P^k$ consist of the vectors comprising $\ell$.

What we wish to do is, for a given $\ell$, "measure" the vectors in nearby fibers relative to the vector space $p^{-1}(\ell)$.  One might think of all the nearby fibers as being somewhat parallel, so orthogonal projection of a vector from some $p^{-1}(\ell')$ onto $p^{-1}(\ell)$ ought to be invertible.  And it's a linear map.

Let $\pi_\ell:\mathbb{R}^k\to \ell$ be orthogonal projection onto $\ell$.  The map $p^{-1}(\ell')\to p^{-1}(\ell)$ defined by $(\ell',v)\mapsto(\ell,\pi_\ell(v))$ is invertible exactly when $\pi_\ell(\ell')$ has dimension $1$.

The largest trivialization containing $\ell$ one can choose using this idea is $U=\{\ell'\in\mathbb{R}P^k:\pi_\ell(\ell')\text{ has dimension }1\}$.  Along this set, you can effectively measure the vectors in $p^{-1}(U)$ using vectors of $p^{-1}(\ell)$.

(There are more details in Milnor and Stasheff's book.)

**Exercise.** Think about how a basis for $p^{-1}(\ell)$ looks when carried over to the other fibers of $U$.

Comment: I understand first and second paragraph.. Third paragraph I have some problem... You said we wish to **measure** how $p^{-1}(l)$ and $p^{-1}(l')$ are related when $l,l'$ are **near by**... fibers can be thought of as parallel.. That is also ok... What I do not understand is "so orthogonal projection of a vector from some[---]" What do you mean by that?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik "measure" and "nearby" are the intuitive notions that vector bundles formalize (the exercise is meant to illustrate some part of "measurement" in terms of a basis).  If you have nearly-parallel lines, you can carry points of one line to the other by orthogonal projection.  When you move your ruler around, it changes length in a sort of special relativity sort of way.  (Another exercise: other linear transformations to carry this ruler around might have worked. What is the difficulty with getting rotations to work out?)